# Windows Access is Denied to file created via ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I have a Windows server with cygwin installed and an sshd server running. I SSH in, and execute the following lines:

```
echo "Hello World!" > /cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/helloworld.txt
chown Administrator /cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/helloworld.txt
chgrp Administrators /cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/helloworld.txt
chmod 777 /cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/helloworld.txt
cmd /c "takeown /S localhost /U Administrator /P "@dm!np@$$" /F C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\helloworld.txt"
```

However, when I try to open the file in the Windows machine through an RDP session, I just get an "Access is denied" error. 
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the commands are running ok? Check the return codes. For example the last one could fail due to the nested quotes

Comment: If I take out the /P switch and type in the password manually, the command just hangs.

Comment: In the RDP session, check what Windows permissions the file has.

Comment: Try with single quotes instead of double, for the password field or for the outer ones

Comment: I second the single quotes suggestion by @golimar.  The `$$` in the password (if that is indeed the password), will expand to the process id of the current shell.  Single quotes will prevent that expansion.